# Android apps migration from Delphi 10.3.1 to 10.3.2

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have two problems after switching to 10.3.2 from 10.3.1

1) When I install the APK on the phone I get information "Google protect blocked APP.... "
   I have the same SDK version in 10.3.1 and 10.3.2.  I get information only for APK under 10.3.2.
   What I should change ?

2) I can't run android projects created in 10.3.1 after compile in 10.3.2.
   I cleaned the library directory in my project. The application compiles, installs and then app stops on the default splash.

**UPDATE FOR POINT 2** - Problem solved

Comment: can post an answer about how you solved the second point?

Comment: Having created Android apps in 10.1 and then recompiled them in 10.2, I can say that there were very few changes I needed to make, but to be sure, step through your code until you find the problems. Once you go to 10.3, which targets a higher API (28), you may ave to put in extra code for explicit permissions for some services.

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout   The solution was very simple but stupid :) I restarted the computer, compiled again,  and now there is no problem.